# RunAction,CCCallFuncN with multiple Variables - Cocos2D

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Is there any way you could send 2 parameters with RunAction?

You see im trying to move a sprite with a label on top, and I have made separate functions for each. Similar to this.

```
     [sprite runAction:
 [CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];


id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self
                                         selector:@selector(spriteLabelMoveFinished:)];
```

Now, I've got 2 questions, 
1-Is there any way to send 2 or more parameters????
2-I was wondering if there's any way to save some memory and do both with one action?

```
    - (void) spriteMoveFinished:(id)sender
{
CCLOG(@"Sprite move finished");
Sprites *sprite = (Sprites *)sender;

[self animateSprite:sprite];

}


- (void) animateSprite:(Sprites *)zprite
    {
CCLOG(@"We're animating sprite"):

Sprites *sprite = nil;

sprite = zprite;


int actualDuration = sprite.speed; //property of sprite

// Create the actions

id actionMove = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:actualDuration
                                    position:ccpMult(ccpNormalize(ccpSub(_player.position,sprite.position)), 10)];

id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self
                                         selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)];
[sprite runAction:
 [CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];


}


- (void) spriteLabelMoveFinished:(CCLabelTTF *)sender
{   

[self animateSpriteLabel:sender];   
}

-(void)animateEnemyHP:(CCLabelTTF *)zpriteLabel
{


CCLabelTTF *spriteLabel = nil;

spriteLabel = zpriteLabel;


int actualDuration = spriteSpeed; //another property


id actionMove = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:actualDuration
                                    position:ccpMult(ccpNormalize(ccpSub(_player.position,spriteLabel.position)), 10)];

id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self
                                         selector:@selector(spriteLabelMoveFinished:)];
[spriteLabel runAction:
 [CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];

}
```

Now, this 4 functions are kind of obvious.

1-Move Sprite if sprite ended moving, we move it again.
2-Move Label towards the same position with the same speed, if the label finishes moving, we move it again.

They both go to the same place.
Is there a way to mix this 4 functions into 2? 
If so, how can I send 2 parameters when the action finishes?
Thanks for your help and your time, have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send more than one parameter, instead CCCallFunc you can use CCCallBlock and call a block of code. Inside the block, you can call your method (selector) with any parameters you want.

A simple example:

```
  CCAction *actionMoveDone = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^()
                                   {
                                       [self spriteMoveFinished:param1 withParam2:param2 andParam3:param3];
                                   }];
```

And a better way is use "self" as block parameter, to prevent memory allocation:

```
  CCAction *actionMoveDone = [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *myNode)
                                   {
                                       [(MyClass*)myNode spriteMoveFinished:param1 withParam2:param2 andParam3:param3];
                                   }];
```

Comment: could you help me with a quick example of how can this be done? Im not that familiar with CCCallBlock :/

Answer (score 0):

try to simplify, that will undoubtedly save 'memory' ... I normally do this with a class that extends CCNode, for example my SoldierMapLayout class does. In the SoldierMapLayout node, i put in the soldier stance animation (idle, walking right-left-up-down), a health bar, an optional label, a 'HP hit' animation when appropriate, an 'XP gained' animation when appropriate, a 'poison cloud' over the head, etc...   and i move the node when the whole thing needs to move. A single animation, with a single call back on move completion.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean but Im a little fuzzy on it, is there any example you could give me or some place that helps out with some design of what you're telling me??
(Aside from cocos2d documentation?)